# VBA code to add duplicates and remove

Tags: vba, excel

I am really stuck on a code for this form.
I want to create a command button that will allow the user to simplify the report and combine all like items and remove the duplicates. This will be used a Purchase request. I've attached a photo of the form here ->
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTse5.png)

[image]

I need the button to find duplicates in column C and sum the totals from column F and then remove duplicates leaving the original behind with a grand total in the QTY menu. Is that possible and still keep it on the same sheet or would it be better to have it duplicate to a new sheet?

Comment: where is the code your stuck on?

Comment: @AsleyGoodwin are you sure it is column C? it seems that the key for searching duplicates should be  or column A

Comment: Yes, column C. The order is based on the frame part number. Column A is just a reference column

Comment: You've found some very generous people to write code for you. It's considered good form to post the code that you _do_ have so people can help fix it.

Comment: @FreeMan the codes I did try writing were deleted after I tested them. It did not occur to me to jot them down, I usually have no problem working through the code on my own, but this one just wouldn't budge. I am still quite new to VBA and this forum. In the future I will keep note to post my original code for others to view.

Comment: Usually my first shot doesn't work quite right either, but then it evolves to a final functional form. I tend to not completely scrap and start from scratch too often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key is column `C`, this macro should do what you want, attach it to the button. To make it changeable easily for the key column, I defined the key as a constant and set it to 3 for now (col C):

```
Sub ProcessForm()
    Dim wholeRange As Range, i As Long, ar
    Const key As Long = 3 ' <-- column C is key. Set to 1 if col A
    With Worksheets("Order")
        Set wholeRange = .Range("A5:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, key).End(xlUp).row)
    End With
    With wholeRange
        ar = .Columns(key).value
        For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
            ar(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Columns(6), .Columns(key), ar(i, 1))
        Next
        .Columns(6).value = ar
        .RemoveDuplicates key
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again A.S.H.Like I said before column A is just a reference column and might be eliminated based on its usefulness. I've also made it so the button was password protected so only certain people can activate this code.

Comment: @AshleyGoodwin I see. The suggested method does use `C` as the key, I only made it flexible for eventual change but that's not mandatory.

Comment: But anyway, I mean it as an advice in general, it is unusual to use a *"Description"* field as a key.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have explained that Column 3 is actually the frame part number, there is a hidden column in between the columns work order and frame #.

Comment: Ah, I see, I did not notice that in the picture. But anyway, the code should work as is, did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did and it works for combining the rows I need. But now I've run into the problem of when it does that it erases the formula in the last column that pulls the vendor name from another sheet. I tried putting it in VBA but it won't insert the formula.
    Range("G5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",VLOOKUP(RC[-4],Metal_Frame,5,FALSE))"

Comment: I didn't know that you had formulas in the range. But I think it's pretty easy to preserve the formulas. Would you try `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Value` in both places inside the `With` bloc?

Comment: There is only a formula in the last column. The other data is pulled from another sheet with a different VBA code.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Using `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` is just to keep the formulas in the range, but the places where there is no formula will be taken as values.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its difficult to say what your stuck on but here is quick  example on How to search duplicates and sum the value

I'm using *[WorksheetFunction.Match Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx)*

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example()
'   // Declare Variables
    Dim DupRow As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Sht
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
'               // Columns 3 (C) DupRow
            DupRow = Application.Match(Cells(i, 3).Value, Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(i - 1, 3)), 0)

            If Not IsError(DupRow) Then
'               // Columns 6 (F) sum Match
                Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(i, 6).Value + Cells(DupRow, 6).Value
                Rows(DupRow).Delete ' Delete DupRow

            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Order")
        With .Range("C5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
            For Each cell in .Cells
                cell.Offset(,3).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Cells, cell, .Offset(,3))
            Next
            .Offset(, -2).Resize(, 7).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3), Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```